# Python Web-Scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to python and for an assignment I had to write a program that fetches a webpage with BeautifulSoup, extract all Paragraphs from it, and extract all words ending with "ing", and in the end save it to a file with the format "Word" + tab + "wordcount" + "newline".

This is my code so far. Is there a more pythonic way to handle this?
Or generally ways to improve the code?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


def main():
    site = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science"
    r = requests.get(site).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    ps = soup.findAll('p')
    fulltext = ''
    for p in ps:
        fulltext += p.get_text()
    words = match_words(fulltext)
    formated_words = sort_and_format(words)
    with open(r"Q1_Part1.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(formated_words)


def match_words(string):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b(\w*ing)\b')
    words = re.findall(pattern, string.lower())
    matching_words = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in matching_words:
            matching_words[word] += 1
        else:
            matching_words[word] = 1
    return matching_words

def sort_and_format(dict):
    ordered_keys = sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True)
    output_string = ''
    for r in ordered_keys:
        output_string += f"{r}\t{dict[r]}\n"
    return output_string
    
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if word in matching_words:
    matching_words[word] += 1
else:
    matching_words[word] = 1
```

If you're checking if a dictionary has a key before adding to it, a `defaultdict` may be a better option:

```
from collections import defaultdict

matching_words = defaultdict(int)
matching_words[word] += 1
```

`int` returns a `0` when called without arguments, and that `0` is used as a default value for the dictionary when the key doesn't exist.

---

```
fulltext = ''
for p in ps:
    fulltext += p.get_text()
```

This isn't very efficient. Performance of `+=` on strings has gotten better in later versions of Python, but it's still generally slower. The typical alternative is using `join`:

```
pieces = [p.get_text() for p in ps]
fulltext = "".join(pieces)

# Or just

fulltext = "".join([p.get_text() for p in ps])
```

Then similarly in `sort_and_format`:

```
output_string = "".join([f"{r}\t{dict[r]}\n"] for r in ordered_keys])
```

---

In `sort_and_format`, you've named the parameter `dict`. This is suboptimal for a couple reasons:

- `dict` is a generic name that doesn't properly describe the data.
- `dict` is the name of a built-in class, and shadowing it makes your code more confusing, and prevents you from using the built-in.

Indicating the type can be helpful though, so I might introduce type hints here

```
from typing import Dict

def sort_and_format(words: Dict[str, int]) -> str:
    . . .
```

This says that the functions accepts a `Dict`ionary mapping `str`ings to `int`s, and returns a `str`ing

---

Also for `sort_and_format`, I've found that when you start sticking `and` into names, that can suggest that the function is doing too much. You may find that the code will make more sense if the sorting and formatting happen separately. That functions can handle purely formatting, and can be handed a sequence to work with instead. If that sequence is sorted, great, if not, also great. It doesn't matter for the purposes of formatting what the sort order is.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Everything was outstandingly helpfull. The list comprehension is so usefull in python data wrangling. Also what do you think is it good practice in Python to specify the inputs and outputs? I come from java and scala and this is one thing which i feel is off and came to bite me in the ass lots of times.

Comment: @elauser No problem. Glad to help. What do you mean though by "Also what do you think is it good practice in Python to specify the inputs and outputs?". The types of the input/output?

Comment: Parameters and return types in functions is what i meant.

Comment: @elauser I recommend using type hints, and also using an IDE like Pycharm that gives type warnings. I find it helps a lot, but it means you need to take the time to consider what types are involved (although that isn't necessarily a bad thing). If you check the Python code that I've posted here for review, you'll see that I use them everywhere.